# Data not being saved from multiple text boxes codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm adding multiple textboxes using JavaScript function dynamically, I want to insert from those boxes into table in codeigniter, but data is not being inserted even not showing any error. can any body get me out of this problem. thanks in advance

my model code

```
public function insert_Job_question($ques_data) {
        $this->db->set($ques_data);
        $this->db->insert('job_question',$ques_data);
    }
```

my controller code is

```
 $questions = $this->input->post('question');
                if (is_array($questions)) {
                    foreach ($questions as $id => $ques) {
                        $ques_data = array(
                            'job_post_id' => $new_job_Id,
                            'question' => $ques
                        );
                        $this->db->insert('job_question', $ques_data);
                   }
                }
 my view code is

<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="about-heading">

            <div class="head-menu"> &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-section">
            <div class="about-content rigs-content">
                <form name="jobpost" action=" <?php echo base_url('employer/job_post/post_job'); ?>" method="post">
                    <h2>Your Job Detail :</h2>

                    <div class="invest-form">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Job Category:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="jobcat" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Category*"  />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Job Title:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="jobtitle" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Title*"  />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Job Type:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="jobtype" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Type*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Preffered Age:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="age" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Title*"  />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Preffered Gender:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="gender" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Type*" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Job Description:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="desc" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Type*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Location:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="location" value="" placeholder="Enter the Country*"  />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Post Code:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="post" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" name="postcode" placeholder="Enter the City*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Salary:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="salaries" name="salary" placeholder="Enter the Salary*" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <li>
                                <label>Qualification:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="qualification" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" name="qualification" placeholder="Enter Benifits*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Category:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="category" class="span12" required name="category" placeholder="Enter Job Tags" />

                            </li>
                                <label>Benifits:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="benefits" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" name="benefits" placeholder="Enter Benifits*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Job Tags:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="jobtags" class="span12" required name="jobtag" placeholder="Enter Job Tags" />

                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Career Level:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="career" class="span12" required name="career" placeholder="Enter Job Tags" />

                            </li>
                          <li>  
                            <label>Country:</label>
                    <?php $countries = getCountriesList(); ?>
                    <select name="company_country">
                        <option>Select your country*</option>
                        <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $country->name ?>" <?php echo(@$userComp->country == $country->name ? 'selected' : '') ?> > <?php echo $country->name; ?></option>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                        </li>    
                            <li class="pull-right">                              
                                <table id="question">

                                    <th>Add Killer Questions</th>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="txtquestion" name="question"/></td>

                                        <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="insertTextBox()" value="Add More"></input></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                            </li>
                            <br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Save As Draft" class="button-next" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="wid-social">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script>  
    var index = 1;
    function insertTextBox(){
            var table=document.getElementById("question");
                var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
                var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
                var t1=document.createElement("input");
                    t1.id = "question"+index;
                    t1.name = "question";
                    cell1.appendChild(t1);
                var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
          index++;  
    }

    var total = 0;
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  if(this.val().length > 0)
   total = total + 1;
});
alert("Number of non-empty textboxes on page are: " + total);

    </script>
```

Comment: Please post the view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line

```
<td><input type="text" id="txtquestion" name="question"/></td>
```

To

```
<td><input type="text" id="txtquestion" name="question[]"/></td>
```

Notice, we added two brackets, to indicate that this is an array.

Then change this line in your JS code

```
t1.name = "question";
```

To

```
t1.name = "question[]"; // Optional use an incremented index t1.name = "question[i]";
```

Then in your Controller you can loop through it or whatever you like.

```
foreach ( $this->input->post('question') as $question)
{
// some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sobiaholic for your help. its working fine for me, thanks again